# AWS S3 - failed to identify the profile information

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flask, mod-wsgi, boto3

I am using boto3 for communicating with AWS S3. I first tried with my local system. It successfully got connected and was working fine. I moved the code to the server(flask-apache2). Now the code is not working. It shows `ProfileNotFound: The config profile (dev) could not be found` exception even though I set the the parameters over `~/.aws/credentials` and `~/.aws/config`

**~/.aws/credentials** file:

```
[dev]
aws_access_key_id = *****************
aws_secret_access_key = *********************
```

**~/.aws/config** file:

```
[default]
region = us-west-2
output = json

[profile dev]
region = us-west-2
output = json
```

This is how I am accessing the profile:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
```

Error Log:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev')
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.912720 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 80, in __init__
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.912836 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]     self._setup_loader()
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.912866 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 120, in _setup_loader
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.912893 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]     self._loader = self._session.get_component('data_loader')
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.912910 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 701, in get_component
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913104 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]     return self._components.get_component(name)
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913121 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 897, in get_component
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913134 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]     self._components[name] = factory()
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913145 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 181, in <lambda>
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913154 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]     lambda:  create_loader(self.get_config_variable('data_path')))
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913163 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 265, in get_config_variable
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913172 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]     elif self._found_in_config_file(methods, var_config):
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913181 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 286, in _found_in_config_file
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913190 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]     return var_config[0] in self.get_scoped_config()
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913198 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 358, in get_scoped_config
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913206 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564]     raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
[Wed Jun 21 05:50:56.913225 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 21586] [remote 103.227.98.117:37564] ProfileNotFound: The config profile (dev) could not be found
```

Comment: Most likely the credentials file in a different user environment than the one who is running it.

Comment: can you suggest some fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution!

I added the AWS Credentials & Config file paths to `apache2 envvars` file. And the problem got solved.

Steps:

```
$sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars
     # Added the following lines
     export AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/home/ubuntu/.aws/config
     export AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE=/home/ubuntu/.aws/credentials

sudo service apache2 reload | sudo service apache2 restart
```

Done! It started working fine!!

I initially tried adding like `AWS_CONFIG_FILE=~/.aws/credentials`. **This didn't work**. Have to give the complete path.